# Tool to track features and bugs that allows end user visibility?

Tags: c#, vb.net, debugging, scrum, beta

I'm looking for a feature request/bug tracking web tool that would allow for the following:

1. Allows end users to enter their feature request.
2. Allows end users to see their feature requests and other requests that are "publicly" visible (from other users) with things like timelines, progress updates, etc
3. Would allow for individual URLs to give to users like `client1.mysite.com` and `client2.mysite.com`
4. Can integrate sign-on information from a current SQL Server

I'm sure that a tool like this must already exist and I'd like to hear feedback from some of the other programmers on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give www.uservoice.com a try.  There are competitors, but I've not used the others.

Their plans include Domain aliasing, single-sign on, and you don't have to support it.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned there are quite a few big players in this area right now. I've had some success with Get Satisfaction: http://getsatisfaction.com/developers/single-sign-on